# Creation of Tag by using maven without maven release plugin

Tags: jenkins

Is there any way to create a tag by passing maven goals without using Maven-Release-Plugin,
My problem is while using maven-release-plugin it creates the tag and the same time that particular release  has done.
My goal is  to create only tag of that particular maven artifact

Comment: when you say tag, do you mean a new version name?

Comment: no muatik,In pom.xml what is the version is present we have to created  the tag  with that particular version and as well as release has done with release plugin, now i have to create only tag but not release

Answer (score 0):

You can create a tag in Jenkins by executing the usual git command

```
git tag <name>
```